# Tools for understanding solution archtitecture

Tags: c#, design-patterns, visual-studio-2012

What tools can I use to get a over view of a solution in C#, I so far used Class diagram and read code, but when code is jumping from one class to other (very hard to keep everything in mind).

What Tools can I use for a Visual studio solution to understand it graphically ideally.

**Not so related information**

Solution is made by senior developer with mix and match of several patterns e.g. factory, abstract, Singleton. I also tried to get Code metric which nearly makes no sense to me as it has high Depth of inheritance, and high class coupling but still 86 score of maintainability.

[image]

Comment: The Code Metrics won't give you a nice overview of how a system functions. Nothing beats a notepad and pen for this though (for me). It's the first thing I do with a new code base.. circles and lines .. sometimes some UML-style arrows too.

Comment: As Simon says, pad and pen.  Draw an overview of the system.  Look some more, start it again, look some more, start it again and keep doing it.  Also bear in mind that there are wildly different ways to visualise the same system.  Look up and understand the 4+1 architecture model, this helps you to understand why the systems engineers draw a completely different diagram for you than the softies.  (And both be right.)

Comment: I would recommend to sketch the system on paper and when you think it's done use MS Visio to refine it.

Answer (score 0):

Try [CodeMaid](http://www.codemaid.net/) Visual Studio extension. It gives plenty of code analysis functionality.